# How to generate vector tile patterns in inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

I want to make a vector seamless tiel for use within inkscape to apply to objects. I have no probs making seamless tiles to export as bitmaps or pngs and they work good in GIMP, but when I follow the guide for making seamless vector tiles, a la: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/TilePattern.html I get seams showing between the tiles. I am also using a coloured bg which might be part of the problem since the examples in the link above are done with a white bg (same colour as the seams).

But funny thing is I have some seamless patterns I made about a year ago available to me in inkscape, transparent background, but then can be applied to a transparent object and laid on top of the object to which I want to apply the pattern. But for the life of me I can't remember how I did it. This would actually be the best, most versatile solution if anyone has a link to another tut shouwing how to make such patterns and save them in inkscape for use with inkscape I would appreciate reading it.

**====**

EDIT:

This link proved super useful in achieving what I wanted: http://www.verysimpledesigns.com/vectors/inkscape-tutorial-seamless-patterns.html‎. It bypasses the whole inkscape patterns selector in fills and shades window and you can create whatever size vector tiled pattern ya want and then clip it onto another object. Perfect and useful for reuse in the future.

It seems odd that there are not more sites with similar solutions out there since this bug in inkscape appears to go back 11, yeap that's right, 11 years!!! Sheesh. I know this is opensource and free, but come on, tiled patterns are a fairly common requirement, and 11 years to ignore a bug like this seems a little over the top. I guess many people who can't afford AI settle for rastered tiled patterns, but there is no need.

Answer (score 1):

Since Inkscaspe 0.92 an extension is included called [Seamless Pattern Extension](https://inkscape.org/en/gallery/item/1358/). It makes creating seamless patterns easy!

First, find the extension in Extensions > Render.

[image]

You will then be asked to choose the size of your new pattern.

[image]

A new document will pop up with instructions on how to create the pattern.

[image]

The important to remember when creating the pattern is to draw only on the Pattern Foreground and Pattern Background layers.

[image]

As you draw on the layers you'll see the preview update, which makes this whole process a lot smoother.

[image]

With the pattern now created you can use it as an Inkscape pattern by using Object > Pattern > Objects to Pattern, or you can use it in other documents by exporting it as a bitmap.

[image]

If you're having problems with small gaps between objects then you may have to [toggle anti-aliaising](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/50850/5182)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I just found out some significant info on it. Hopefully someone would benefit.

First of all, make sure both your tile contents and clipping mask have integer coordinates. Otherwise seams appear.

I also found a way of forcing the tile size even if you did not group the square alone first (like the tutorials OP posted).

You have to set several properties:

- inkscape:tile-cx
- inkscape:tile-cy
- inkscape:tile-x0
- inkscape:tile-y0
- inkscape:tile-h
- inkscape:tile-w

on the node you wish to clone (e.g. a group). The first four values don't seem to matter (but they **are** required, even if they are zero), but you want to set the width and height (e.g. 64x64). It appears these values are used by the clone tool when you set the "use saved size and position of the tile" checkbox.

Then cloning the tile should give you the desired results.

Inkscape is great, gives you so much power!